# Prove that, given integers a, b, and c such that a mod 6 = 3, b mod 8 = 3, and c mod 10 = 3, (a + b + c) mod 6 is odd.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I need to prove that, given integers $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that

$a\mod6=3$, $b\mod8=3$, and $c\mod10=3$ then,

$(a + b + c) \mod6$ is odd.

Here's what I have tried.

By using the definition of mod and quotient remainder theorem, I get

> $a = 6x + 3$
>
> $b = 8y + 3$
>
> $c = 10z + 3$

I then consider $a + b + c$:

> $a + b + c = 6x + 3 + 8y + 3 + 10z + 3 = 6x + 8y + 10z + 9$

I know that I need to get that in the form $6q + r $ where q is an integer and r is odd.
But it doesn't look like I can manipulate that equation to get it to be in the form $6q$ ... unless I'm not seeing something or I need to somehow use the definition of odd somewhere.

**Update:**
I was able to show that $a + b + c$ is odd, by getting this:

> $a + b + c = 2(3x + 4y + 5z + 4) + 1$

But now I'm stuck on how I would show that "an odd integer" mod 6 = an odd integer.

Comment: Showing that something is "odd mod 6" is the same as just showing that it is odd.

Comment: @alex.jordan Ok, I was able to show that a + b + c is odd. But how would I go about showing "odd mod 6" = an odd integer?

Comment: You have some number — you want this number modulo 6. You subtract (or add) 6 until you have something between 0 and 5. But when you add or subtract even number from some other number, parity doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An integer is "odd mod 6" if and only if it is just plain odd. The same is true for 8 and 10. So you have 3 odd numbers, which add up to an odd number, which is "odd mod 6".

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $a+b+c\equiv 2y+4z+3\equiv r\pmod6,$ where $r$ is odd.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all $6x=0\mod 6$

Then, $8y+10z = 2y+4z \mod 6$ and for any $y,z$ — $2y+4z$ is even number. So $2y+4z \mod 6$ is even too.

And of course $9 =3 \mod 6$